# Add custom page to admin menu visible only to editor users

Tags: php, wordpress, backend, admin, custom-backend

I want to build a custom assign management and display its results in the wordpress backend.

I added a new admin menu item like this:

```
     add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');
     function register_custom_menu_page()
     {
add_menu_page('Approval', 'Approval Management','add_users', 'manage_approval.php', '','images/check.gif',86);

}
```

this is working fine with admin login but i need this to show when editor gets logged in.

Please let me know the correct solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter of the [**add_menu_page()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) function is `$capabilities`, which represents:

> "*The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.*"

In your case you set `'add_users'`, which is a *capability* that only the *admin* users have, so it will be only displayed to administrators.

You just need to change it to other capability that editors have, for example `'edit_pages'`.

Note that this will make it visible for *editors* and also for *admins*, since they also have that *capability*.

See the complete list of [**WordPress Roles & Capabilities**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) for further info.