# Wordpress Add my plugin admin menu to my admin new role

Tags: wordpress

- I created a new plugin including a admin menu (add_menu_page)
- I created also a new role "my_plugin_admin_role" 
  Now I would like to add my plugin menu only to my new role. How can'I do this.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: use capability option for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add capability for you new role and use this capability in add_menu_page.

you can use this [referral link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768664/add-custom-page-to-admin-menu-visible-only-to-editor-users#answer-22769097)